# DynamoDB can't get item by range key?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to get a single record from a DynamoDB table using a column defined as a `RANGE` key, but when I do I get this error:

```
The provided key element does not match the schema
```

Here is how I'm creating and seeding the table:

```
// Create words table
if(!tableExists('words')) {
  console.log('Creating words table');
  await createTable({
    TableName: 'words',
    KeySchema: [
      { AttributeName: 'id', KeyType: 'HASH' },
      { AttributeName: 'index', KeyType: 'RANGE' },
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions: [
      { AttributeName: 'id', AttributeType: 'S' },
      { AttributeName: 'index', AttributeType: 'N' },
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: { ReadCapacityUnits: 5, WriteCapacityUnits: 5 },
  });
  await wait(5000);
  console.log('done');
} else {
  console.log('words table found. Skipping.')
}

// Seed words
let index = 0;
for(let word of words) {
  console.log(`Adding word ${word}`);
  const params = {
    TableName: tableName('words'),
    Item: {
      id: word,
      index: index,
    },
  };
  await db.put(params).promise();
  console.log('added');
  index++;
}
```

And here's how I'm trying to fetch the record:

```
const db = require('../db');
const getResponseItem = response => response.Item;

module.exports = function loadWordByIndex(index) {
  return db.get({
    TableName: 'talk_stem.words',
    Key: {
      index,
    },
  })
  .promise()
  .then(getResponseItem);
};
```

What's the point of defining a `RANGE` key if I can't even reference it in queries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you make a `get` you can only ask for an item. Get returns (or not) one single item which corresponds to the full key, otherwise *"The provided key element does not match the schema"*. Example:

```
const id = 'marmelade';
const index = 5;

db.get({
  TableName: 'talk_stem.words',
  Key: {
    id,
    index,
  },
}).promise()
```

With `get` you look for one item!

**What you need is a `query` ([see doc here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#query-property))**. You can imagine something like this:

```
db.query({
  TableName: 'talk_stem.words',
  KeyConditionExpression: '#id = :id AND #index BETWEEN :indexLow AND :indexHigh',
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#id': 'id',
    '#index': 'index',
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':id': id, # a fixed id
    ':indexLow': 3,
    ':indexHigh': 9,
  },
}).promise()
```

Keep in mind that with DynamoDB `get` and `query` need to mention the partition key. Always. When you want to get items for partition keys you do not know, you can only do an "expensive" `scan`.

Comment: Are you sure you always need to mention the partition key? I think I have some queries that only mention the range key

Comment: The Partition Key is mandatory in a query. **`KeyConditionExpression — (String)`
The condition must perform an equality test on a single partition key value.** Follow the doc link in the answer above. I really doubt it is possible to have queries with only range key.

Comment: What happens when there is more than one item? Does GetItem return just the first item?

Comment: @piritocle • `GetItem` uses a full key. One key --> one item. There is only one item matching that key. • The `query` returns an **array of items** that match the `KeyConditionExpression`.